# How do I avoid writing so much boilerplate for queries in ADO.NET on .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am currently working on a project that needs to target .NET 2.0, and it must read tables from a SQL Server database. I know a bit of ADO.NET but it requires a massive amount of boilerplate since I need to add each parameter individually and map each column of each table individually. I have not found any wrapper library that works on .NET 2.0. Is there any way to avoid writing so much boilerplate?

Comment: what about using an ORM?

Comment: Can you go from 2.0 to 3.5? You have more options of ORMs in 3.5

Comment: [There is an old version of the Enterprise Library that works with .net 2.0.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650466.aspx). But I would look at typed datasets first as Rahul suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid writing so much boilerplate?

No there isn't but you can consider two possible things

1. You can wrap all your queries using `stored procedure` and call that procedure from your code but still you will have bind the procedure `IN/OUT` parameters.
2. You can consider using `strongly typed dataset` which will automatically generate the table(s) and map all the procedures with respective method call.

See [HOW TO: Create and Use a Typed DataSet by Using Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/320714)

In case you are wondering what is `Typed Dataset` then right click in your project -> select add new item -> in the opened window select `Data` and then select `DataSet` ... you will see something like below

[image]

Comment: @Magnus, that's a too broad question. read about it in MSDN or search in Google about it. Moreover, I provided one url in answer go through it. Try creating a typed dataset in a sample projecct and see how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of tasks can benefit from boilerplates or templates. For those sorts of activities, I use NimbleText. You can use it to generate all kinds of things, from a sql table with C# objects and stored procs to handle typical insert/update/deletes, to executing SQL (or calling a stored proc) and mapping the returned data to properties in an object.

Of course, you will need to institute some guidelines for it to all fit together, but if you do, NimbleText can make your life easier.

http://nimbletext.com/